# Teste de hipóteses de diferença de médias no pacote Survey do R

Tags: r

Por favor, utilizando o pacote Survey, como fazer um teste de hipóteses de diferença de médias? i.e. se a média amostral de 2003 é a mesma em 2008 para uma certa variável. 
Estou trabalhando com dados do PNAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função que você terá que usar é chamada `svyttest`.

Nos exemplos, quando você usa `help(svytest)` ele faz da seguinte forma:

```
data(api)
dclus2<-svydesign(id=~dnum+snum, fpc=~fpc1+fpc2, data=apiclus2)
svyttest(enroll~comp.imp, dclus2)
```

Neste exemplo ele compara a média do número de alunos inscritos em escolas americanas que atingiram ou não uma "medida de melhoria comparável".

No seu caso você deve ter um objeto criado pela função `svydesign` certo?
Então para testar basta usar a função `svyttest`da seguinte forma:

```
svyttest(variavel_que_vc_quer_comparar~ano_como_fator, objeto_svydesign)
```

Em todo caso, seria interessante se você fornecesse uma pequena amostra dos seus dados para quem for tentar responder, poder ver se está funcionando para o seu problema.